# Extract from dataframe rows based on common values between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that i need to extract the value Id from and store every row in dataframe A inside dataframe B based on their common Ids, for example:

For those two dataframes i would like to definetly remove the row values from Dataframe A that have the values 23, 50, 41 that are common column values between A and B, and move those rows into dataframe C.
The output i am trying to achieve is the following:

As for any code attempts, i didn't do anything besides merging, but it doesn't remove the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an indexing problem:

```
# keep the wanted columns
df_c = df_a[df_a['Id'].isin(df_b['Id'])]

# remove those in the original dataframe
df_a = df_a[~df_a['Id'].isin(df_b['Id'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filtering:

```
mask = df_a['Id'].isin(df_b['Id'])
df_c,df_a = df_a[mask],df_a[~mask]
```